# My for loop increment seems to be wrong

Tags: java, for-loop

I am doing a question for college on cryptography. Part of my program is that I want to get the power x such that (2744^x) % 24852977 = 8414508. I have a loop that increases a double by 0.001. My question is this: instead of my loop increasing by 0.001 each time it shows a number a lot longer in decimal places. Is this to do with the long MIN/MAX value and if so how would i be able to fix this, or can anyone explain were I'm going wrong? Here is a sample of my increment. How do get the cut off point of 4 decimal places.

10.276999999989387
10.277099999989387
10.277199999989387
10.277299999989387
10.277399999989386
10.277499999989386
10.277599999989386
10.277699999989386
10.277799999989385

```
    import java.lang.*;
    public class crypt {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        long p =24852977;//variables
        long g = 2744;
        long sum = 8414508;
        long c1 = 15268076;
        long c2 = 743675;

        for(double i=0; i<=p; i=i+0.0001)//loop for increasing the power in next part of the program
        {
            long num=(long)(Math.pow((long)g, i));//number = g to the power of i
            System.out.println(i);// just to check
            if(num % p == sum)//my equation
            {
                System.out.println(i);//print the power that satisfy's this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The floating point types used by modern PC-type computers can't represent all possible real values, so there will be rounding errors.

Comment: If you are trying to get a number that you can raise 2744 to the power of, with a result that is 8414508 in modulus 24852977, then this is completely the wrong thing to do.  Your answer should be an integer, not a floating point number.  The power won't be equal to 8414508; it will be 8414508 plus some multiple of 24852977.  You have worked out entirely the wrong quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the internal representation of numbers is binary. So, there is not necessarily an exact binary representation for every decimal number. That is, there is no exact representation of your 0.0001 increment and a rounding error is expected.